# Electron Renderer Processes OOM only when DevTools Open

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium, devtools, renderer

I have an electron application with a renderer process that displays large images (~300MB). The image data is received over a websocket connection in a web worker, where I am using rxjs for the websocket management.

When I have Chrome DevTools open, the renderer crashes with the following message from electron:

```
Renderer process oom - see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging for potential debugging information.
```

When I do not have the DevTools open, the renderer process does NOT crash. I have tried setting the flag in Electron before launching the renderer process: `--js-flags="--max-old-space-size=[memory size in MB]"`, which helped alleviate some crashes I had been seeing even with DevTools closed, but nomatter how high I set that number the process still consistently crashes when DevTools are open and a large message is recieved over websocket. I do not see any high memory usage from the process in Task Manager on Windows 10.

After extensive debugging, I've narrowed down the renderer crash to immediately when the large websocket message is received. I set a breakpoint and console log message at the first point where data is available in JavaScript and they are not caught/shown before the renderer process crashes. So my guess is that with DevTools open there is some kind of memory issue. It can't be a problem with rxjs, since it works fine with DevTools closed. Is there some kind of separate memory limit for the Chrome DevTools that I'm running into here?